# Is there data science reading for general but educated public in Russian?

Tags: data-mining

Can someone point me to a well written reading (preferably, up to 2 pages) in Russian on the subject of "what is data science?"

The audience is educated people, but not specialists in statistics. The focus must be on applications, not theory and research.

Comment: Have you tried to post your question somewhere on russian-speaking data analysis forums?

Comment: @ttnphns No, I know there are russian-speaking members here, and don't know the forums you mentioned

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your needs. I would recommend to translate from English any introductory notes you can find on data science. There are vast amount of such notes and short essays on the web. If you would like to learn more about data science and machine learning, you could look at the **coursera** course on Introduction to Machine Learning given by Higher School of Economics (in Russian):

https://www.coursera.org/learn/vvedenie-mashinnoe-obuchenie